# How to get mapped values in Vim and save them

Tags: vim, keymapping

Let's say I have the next mapping:

```
imap a AAA
vmap b BBB
```

I need a way to get value of mappings.
The next is not suitable for me, because I need to operate by returned mapped values:

```
imap a
vmap b
```

I'm looking for for something like these functions:

```
let a = getimap("a")   => a = "AAA"
let b = getvmap("b")   => b = "BBB"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `maparg()` function is what you are looking for. `:h maparg(` to see detail.

to your question, if you have those two mapping, you could:

```
let a =  maparg('a','i')
let b =  maparg('b','v')
```

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking when I posted it, I wrote `let a = echo maparg(...)`  :-/ fixed..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `maparg()` to do this, like so:

```
let a = maparg("a")
```

You can also specify the mode if you only want mappings for one mode, and it will optionally populate a dictionary with every detail of the mapping (things like `<silent>`, etc.).  See `:h maparg()` for all the details.

Comment: `{mode}` argument is needed for his question